# swiftを用いたPUSH通知にてデータだけ先に受け取る（NCMB）

Tags: ios, swift4, push-notification

現在Swiftを使ってPUSH通知の実装を行なっています。
サービスはNCMBを使っているのですが、
私の希望として、PUSH通知を受け取ったらすぐにデータだけをアプリに反映させたいのです。
この分野の知識は乏しいため、初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、
わかる方いれば教えていただきたいです。
また、Content_availableを有効にした際にアプリのバッジが増えないのですが、
どのようにしたら通知が来たと同時に増やすことができるのでしょうか？？

この二つをお聞きしたいです。
ソースコードなど必要なものがあれば書き加えますので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: データだけをアプリに反映させていけれども、xxとなってしまうのだろうと思うのですが、xxの部分は何ですか？ また、yyとしたけれどもバッチが増えないと思うのですが、yyの部分（コード）を提示してください。

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
       ＜データの取得のための変数宣言＞
        switch application.applicationState {       
        case .inactive:
           ＜データ取得の処理、バッジ追加＞
            break
        case .background:
            ＜データ取得の処理等＞
            break
        }
          completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

この部分で、Xcodeの実機テストではバッジの増加とデータの受け取りがうまくいくのですが、TestFlightの内部テストでは両方がうまくいきません。PUSH通知を選択した際に両方が反映されます。